# Linked List Design

Tags: c#

The other day in a local .NET group I attend the following question came up: "Is it a valid interview question to ask about Linked Lists when hiring someone for a .NET development position?"

Not having a computer science degree and being a self taught developer my response was that I did not feel it was appropriate as I in 5 years of developing with .NET had never been exposed to linked lists and did not hear any compelling reason for a use for one.

However the person commented that it is a very common interview question so I decided when I left that I would do some reasearch on linked lists and see what I might be missing.

I have read a number of posts on stack overflow and various google searches and decided the best way to learn about them was to write my own .NET classes to see how they worked from the inside out.

Here is my class structure

Single Linked List

Constructor

```
public SingleLinkedList(object value);

// Public Properties  
public bool IsTail;
public bool IsHead;
public object Value;
public int Index;
public int Count;

// private fields not exposed to a property  
private SingleNode firstNode;  
private SingleNode lastNode;  
private SingleNode currentNode;
```

Methods

```
public void MoveToFirst();
public void MoveToLast();
public void Next();
public void MoveTo(int index);
public void Add(object value);
public void InsertAt(int index, object value);
public void Remove(object value);
public void RemoveAt(int index);
```

Questions I have:

What are typical methods you would expect in a linked list?

What is typical behaviour when adding new records? For example if I have 4 nodes and I am currently positioned in the second node and perform Add() should it be added after or before the current node? Or should it be added to the end of the list?

Some of the designs I have seen explaining things seem to expose outside of the LinkedList class the Node object. In my design you simply add, get, remove values and know nothing about any node object.

Should the Head and Tail be placeholder objects that are only used to define the head/tail of the list?

I require my Linked List be instantiated with a value which creates the first node of the list which is essentially the head and tail of the list. Would you change that ?

What should the rules be when it comes to removing nodes. Should someone be able to remove all nodes?

Here is my Double Linked List

Constructor

```
public DoubleLinkedList(object value);
```

Properties

```
public bool IsHead;
public bool IsTail;
public object Value;
public int Index;
public int Count;
```

Private fields not exposed via property

```
private DoubleNode currentNode;
```

Methods

```
public void AddFirst(object value);
public void AddLast(object value);
public void AddBefore(object existingValue, object value);
public void AddAfter(object existingValue, object value);
public void Add(int index, object value);
public void Add(object value);
public void Remove(int index);
public void Next();
public void Previous();
public void MoveTo(int index);
```

Comment: Why not make it generic?

Comment: That is funny I thought about adding a comment in my post that I could have made it generic but I was just playing around and not really looking for usability. Rather just trying to understand linked lists and what methods/behaviour it should have. 

Once I get some feedback I will finish up my classes and likely then refactor then to use generics as you hinted to.

Comment: @Jim: Making it generic is requires only minimal extra work, but it's easier to do it in advance rather than rewriting all your signatures.

Comment: @Jim: it seems like you've merged the iterator function for enumerating the list with the list itself.  These are really two different concepts and there are some good uses for a separate iterator.

Comment: There's some credibility to making this an interview question.  You re-implemented a class that already exists in the framework.  Knowing what's in the box is important.  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: @Hans:  The purpose of creating this was not to create something useable. Yes I was already aware that .NET already included a linked list (however it is a doubly linked list) and I wanted to experiment with both single, double and circular. Rather the point was to understand how linked lists worked internally and why it was being made as such an important question for an interview.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your LinkedList remembers where it is at, then can perform various actions accordingly. I'd prefer a simpler design like below (this is Java, though):

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    private int size;
    private Node<T> head;

    public int size();
    public T get(int index);
    public void add(T newObject);
    public void remove(int index);
    public void remove(Object object);
}

class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node<T> next;
    Node<T> prev; // only applicable for doubly linked list
}
```

So the interface is the same, whether it's a singly or doubly linked list. Some designs have a reference to the end of the list, so it's faster to append stuff at the end, but for simplicity, let's skip that. It's still a (conventionally accepted) linked list.

Basic data structures and algorithms are very useful. People often don't believe/understand that things they don't know are actually useful. Sure, the point of learning such a thing is not to implement a tree when you go to work. It helps you to reason about the cost (in space and time) of what you do, or convince yourself whether a piece of code is correct or not.

If you're interested, there is a course with videos from MIT [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/CourseHome/index.htm), or you can check out [this course](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=11f4f422-5670-4b4c-889c-008262e09e4e) from Stanford, which involves less math. I hope you find these fun to learn.

Good luck :)

Comment: Looked over the links provided and looks like they will provide days worth of fun ;-) Was not aware of these 2 great resources.

Comment: That's a great public interface for an ArrayList, not so much for a linked list.  To iterate the list using your interface requires O(N^2).

Comment: Yes I know that. But in Java, an Iterator would be used to iterate over the list. The Iterator would have some intimacy with the list that allows it to "resume" from the current node. What I wanted was transparency, meaning no difference between an interface for an ArrayList and Linkedlist. Here I assume we don't care yet about performance?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to just mimic a reasonably well-thought out implementation from C++.  One such implementation is SGI's [Linked List](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html).  Note that the page I refer to is not code, it's a list of signatures and definitions much like the one you provided.

Linked Lists are somewhat too low level for the average C# programmer to need to actually be thinking about them in normal circumstances.  Usually, a basic understanding of how they work and the complexity of the different operations involved is sufficient, e.g. concatenating two linked lists can be done in O(1) time.

Note: Take note of the "Model of" section of the SGI page, since each think lists are a "model of" provides complexity guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways to implement a Linked List, but they ultimately all boil down to a series of objects each with a pointer to the next object.  The question then is **"What other features do I require to accomplish what I need with a Linked List data structure?"**

In the context of an interview question, I would be less concerned with "what methods do I need?" and more concerned with how to reason about the Linked List's structure enough to implement any arbitrary method that an interviewer would ask.

However, if you are looking for more real world type scenarios of Linked Lists, I would suggest you look at the API design of the [Java Linked List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), and the [.Net Linked List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) implementations.

Comment: Corey, thanks for the links. Those look just like what I needed.

Comment: Any example questions you can think of that would help me to understand using my design?

Also I noticed that both Linked Lists seem to take the Node object as the parameter for adding, removing in many of the cases. I can see that certainly helps make your operations (0)1 since you have the previous and next reference but not know the use case for linked lists not sure what makes the most sense.

Comment: Generally you could use them in any case where you need a collection with a dynamic size.  Are you familar with the List<T> collection?  Its implemented with an array behind the scenes but you could also reimplement the same collection with a linked list behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

> What are typical methods you would
>   expect in a linked list?

Add(), AddAt(), Remove(), RemoveAt(), ElementAtTop(), ElementAtLast(), ElementAt(),

> What is typical behaviour when adding
>   new records? For example if I have 4
>   nodes and I am currently positioned in
>   the second node and perform Add()
>   should it be added after or before the
>   current node? Or should it be added to
>   the end of the list?

Add(): The functionality of this method depends on the way you are implementing the linked list. Say, if you are implementing [STACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)#Linked_list) using linked list, this method would add the new element (node) at TOP position. While if your are implementing [QUEUE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Stacks_and_Queues#Linked_List_Implementation_2) using linked list then the element will be added to last position.

> > Some of the designs I have seen
> >     explaining things seem to expose
> >     outside of the LinkedList class the
> >     Node object. In my design you simply
> >     add, get, remove values and know
> >     nothing about any node object.
>
> Should the Head and Tail be
>   placeholder objects that are only used
>   to define the head/tail of the list?

I think **YES**. They would be useful to traverse or reverse the linked list.

> I require my Linked List be
>   instantiated with a value which
>   creates the first node of the list
>   which is essentially the head and tail
>   of the list. Would you change that ?

I'm not sure if I understood you. But I would also implement it in the same way.

> What should the rules be when it comes
>   to removing nodes. Should someone be
>   able to remove all nodes?

Remove(): Same explaination as in Add(). Do refer the links in Add().

Comment: Using indexes in a linked list results in poor performance.  Usually the API helps prevent this mistake by omitting functions that work on indexes.  Instead, there is some form of iterator and functions for InsertBefore(iterator) and InsertAfter(iterator).

Comment: I guess I didn't advised to use indexes. Implementing AddAt() should be ofcourse done using some traversal algorithm.